# Angular and using a JSON from an API

Tags: angular

This is the response that I receive from the api in JSON

```
{
   "content":[
      {
         "id":"4354345",
         "name":"asdasd",
         "stuff":null
      },
         {
         "id":"4353345",
         "name":"fgdfgddd",
         "stuff":null
      },
         {
         "id":"4353425",
         "name":"as11111dasd",
         "stuff":null
      }

   ],
   "pageable":{
      "sort":{
         "sorted":false,
         "unsorted":true,
         "empty":true
      },
      "offset":0,
      "pageNumber":0,
      "pageSize":1000,
      "paged":true,
      "unpaged":false
   },
   "totalPages":1,
   "totalElements":75,
   "last":true,
   "number":0,
   "sort":{
      "sorted":false,
      "unsorted":true,
      "empty":true
   },
   "size":1000,
   "first":true,
   "numberOfElements":75,
   "empty":false
}
```

My objective is to itenerate the "Content" part of the JSON,the

"id":"4354345",
"name":"asdasd",
"stuff":null

in a table like this:

```
     <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let data of dataContent; index i">
                          {{data[i].id}}
                          {{data[i].name}}
                          {{data[i].stuff}}
          </tr>
      </tbody>
```

I'm doing it as follows:

```
 ngOnInit(){
       this.api.getAll((error,res) => {
           this.data = res;
           this.dataContent = this.data.content;
      });
  }
```

if I do a console.log of dataContent[0].id or other variables, it works, but why doesn't it show anything in the html and the console is giving errors

Comment: Please paste the error

Comment: What are those errors? Try debugging it or post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let data of dataContent">
                          {{data.id}}
                          {{data.name}}
                          {{data.stuff}}
          </tr>
      </tbody>
```

No need to use index and I here

Or if you want I you have to

```
<tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let data of dataContent; let i = index">
                       <td>   {{data.id}}</td>  
                       <td>     {{data.name}}</td>  
                      <td>      {{data.stuff}}</td>  
          </tr>
      </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to access the `index` in this case, when you use `*ngFor` directive, you're looping `dataContent` and `let data` refers to one value in each iteration. Just:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let data of dataContent">
    <td>{{data.id}}</td>
    <td>{{data.name}}</td>
    <td>{{data.stuff}}</td>
</tr>
```

---

**If** you really need to use the index (for any other case), the issues is the `index i` part, correct it to `index as i` (notice the missing **as**)

```html
<tr *ngFor="let data of dataContent; index as i">
    <td>{{data[i].id}}</td>
    ...
</tr>
```

Again, you don't need the **index** in this case, at least not for the portion of code you shared.

---

Learn more about `*ngFor` [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf).

Answer (score 0):

The HTML template needs to be corrected, `data` variable in the loop will hold one object in the array.

```
<tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let data of dataContent">
          <td>{{data.id}}</td>
          <td>{{data.name}}</td>
          <td>{{data.stuff}}</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```